# angular reactive form does not hit api when form validation is applied

Tags: angular

I have a form which has to be submitted after checking form validations. But when I submit the form it does not to make a request to API.

*my component.html file*

```html
       <form
          class="forms"
          [formGroup]="addContainerForm"
          (ngSubmit)="addAnalyticsSubmit(addContainerForm.value)"
        >
       // some code
       </form>
```

*my component.ts file*

```js
       addContainerForm(v){
            this.new = v
           const a = {
      Name: this.new.nameValue,
       Coordinates: this.coordinates,
         };
       if (this.addContainerForm.valid) {
        this.service.postContainer(a).subscribe(
      (res: any) => {
      console.log(res)})
        }

           }
```

I don't know why API is not hit when the check condition is applied for form validation. Please, tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You should try to debug your formgroup to get th validation errros and what's not working with it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not shared enough information to understand your problem.
Angular official docs have very well explained the basics of forms https://angular.io/guide/http

Also the validation has been explained here.
https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Answer (score 0):

I have added unnecessary fields in the formbuilder group which i am not using in my form due to which it always return false from form validation.